# Width in Postgres EXPLAIN?

Tags: explain, postgresql-9.5

Explain plan in Postgres has width, which (per [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/using-explain.html)) is:

> Estimated average width of rows output by this plan node (in bytes).

My question: **when will width be 0**? Because in examples from docs, it sometimes is, like below:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 < 100;

                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on tenk1  (cost=5.07..229.20 rows=101 width=244)
   Recheck Cond: (unique1 < 100)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tenk1_unique1  (cost=0.00..5.04 rows=101 width=0)
         Index Cond: (unique1 < 100)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer is in the article you are referring to:

> Here the planner has decided to use a two-step plan: the child plan
>   node visits an index to find the locations of rows matching the index
>   condition, and then the upper plan node actually fetches those rows
>   from the table itself.

Word `Output` here means physical read of *values*. Child plan does not read values, it only reads *locations* (addresses) of rows, then parent plan actually reads the values. And next sentence provides explanation why two step process is chosen:

> Fetching rows separately is much more expensive than reading them
>   sequentially, but because not all the pages of the table have to be
>   visited, this is still cheaper than a sequential scan. (The reason for
>   using two plan levels is that the upper plan node sorts the row
>   locations identified by the index into physical order before reading
>   them, to minimize the cost of separate fetches. The "bitmap" mentioned
>   in the node names is the mechanism that does the sorting.)

Later in the text you'll find examples of two child processes where one process has `width=244` and the other `width=0`. Usually child process will fetch row locations with 0 output, and then parent process actually output rows. It is not used always, but there are situations when it is faster than reading rows straight away.